# XCode documentation viewer scrolls back to "home" position automatically

Tags: xcode

And annoyingly!

This happens intermittently. I want to say it's just in 3.2 but I was seeing it a little bit before then too. Basically, what happens typically is when I view the documentation for a Class, and scroll down to say, the properties, once I stop scrolling the viewer will scroll all the way back up to the top as if I had just hit "home." Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now a documentation update available that fixes this issue. (Xcode Preferences -> Documentation)

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue. That was caused by cursor hovering to method names in the "Tasks" section. I use a iMac 20" C2D version with Snow Leopard and Xcode 3.2. Once thought that it might be the microsoft mouse driver, but disable the driver didn't solve this.

Please file a bug to http://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: Yes, some of the links in the newer documentation are causing this.